# Splitting list to many lists with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having such code to make 4 lists from one with my conditions. It is splitting depends on sign of elements of lists.
Like I want to get list with all positive,list with lists where first elements are positive and second are negative ,etc...And all combination like this.
It is easy to create 4 lists using filter when all lists are containts only 2 elements.

```
vals=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]>=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]<=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]>=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]<=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]<=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]<=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
```

Here is my output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (1, -1)]
[(0, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)]
```

But if length of my elements is 3 or more, what can I do not to write all the condionts( there will be 2 ** 3 situations and 2 ** 4 situations for len=4)
For example here is my input for n=3 and example of situation when I want to filter this by "there are no negative" and "first-negative-other not negative"

```
vals=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, -1, 0), (0, -1, 1), (0, -1, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 0), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1)]
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]>=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>=0,new_f))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[2]>=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[0]<=0,vals))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>=0,new_f))
new_f=list(filter(lambda x:x[2]>=0,new_f))
print(new_f)
```

Here is output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 1)]
```

So I need some kinds of automatization of this process to use it with longer arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` over the two filter functions with a `repeat` of the size of the tuples in your input, then `zip` the filter functions with individual items in each tuple and only output the tuple if all filters are satisfied:

```
[[t for t in vals if all(f(i) for (f, i) in zip(filters, t))] for filters in product(((0).__le__, (0).__ge__), repeat=len(vals[0]))]
```

so that given your sample input:

```
vals = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, -1, 0), (0, -1, 1), (0, -1, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 0), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1)]
```

This returns:

```
[[(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (0, 1, 0),
  (0, 1, 1),
  (1, 0, 0),
  (1, 0, 1),
  (1, 1, 0),
  (1, 1, 1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, -1),
  (0, 1, 0),
  (0, 1, -1),
  (1, 0, 0),
  (1, 0, -1),
  (1, 1, 0),
  (1, 1, -1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (0, -1, 0),
  (0, -1, 1),
  (1, 0, 0),
  (1, 0, 1),
  (1, -1, 0),
  (1, -1, 1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, -1),
  (0, -1, 0),
  (0, -1, -1),
  (1, 0, 0),
  (1, 0, -1),
  (1, -1, 0),
  (1, -1, -1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (0, 1, 0),
  (0, 1, 1),
  (-1, 0, 0),
  (-1, 0, 1),
  (-1, 1, 0),
  (-1, 1, 1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, -1),
  (0, 1, 0),
  (0, 1, -1),
  (-1, 0, 0),
  (-1, 0, -1),
  (-1, 1, 0),
  (-1, 1, -1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (0, -1, 0),
  (0, -1, 1),
  (-1, 0, 0),
  (-1, 0, 1),
  (-1, -1, 0),
  (-1, -1, 1)],
 [(0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, -1),
  (0, -1, 0),
  (0, -1, -1),
  (-1, 0, 0),
  (-1, 0, -1),
  (-1, -1, 0),
  (-1, -1, -1)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of lists.  The index of each large list is the binary direction of the comparison: `1` or `True` for positive, `0` or `False` for negative.  Call that the `mask`.

Iterate through all possible masks, 0 through 2^n-1.  For each mask, convert the Boolean vector to a sequence of coefficients.  For instance, the mask `9` is binary `1001`, a coefficient sequence [1, -1, -1, 1].  Multiply the tuple by the mask; for instance,

```
(0, 1, -1, 1) * [1, -1, -1, 1] => [0, -1, 1, 1]
```

Use the `all` function to filter the entire vector, given the `mask` and the `element` from your list of candidates.

```
all(bit >= 0 for bit in 
    [element[i] * mask[i] for i in len(element)])
```

Now, wrap that in a loop the iterates through your mask values.  If you're persistent enough, you can create the entire list of 2^n filtered lists in a single line of code, using `all` and nested comprehensions.  I suggest leaving that for late-night hacking, not problem-solving.

Also note that `itertools.permutations` will be happy to generate masks for you.